# Usar uma pasta layout para mais de um tamanho

Tags: android, android-layout

Eu tenho um Tablet(7") e um smatphone(5").

Minhas pastas de layout são:

**layout** > Possui quase todos os layouts

**layout-large** > Uma das telas(Tela A) ira se comportar diferente para largos

**layout-normal-land** > Uma das telas(Tela B) ira se comportar diferente para normais

Até ai o resultado é o seguinte:

**Tela A:**

- **tablet**, aparesenta a modificação
- **smatphone** nao apresenta a modificação

**Tela B:**

- **tablet**(land), aparesenta a modificação
- **smatphone**(land) apresenta a modificação

Se o tablet é considerado **large** porque ele é afetado por **normal** ?
Como eu faço para contornar isso?

Eu não quero fazer inúmeros layouts!

Comment: Qual é a `minSdkVersion` da sua aplicação?

Comment: É a 17 ( android 4 )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A razão é simples, veja o que diz a [documentação](http://developer.android.com/intl/pt-br/guide/practices/screens_support.html#qualifiers):

> Be aware that, when the Android system picks which resources to use at runtime, it uses certain logic to determine the "best matching" resources. That is, the qualifiers you use don't have to exactly match the current screen configuration in all cases in order for the system to use them. **Specifically, when selecting resources based on the size qualifiers, the system will use resources designed for a screen smaller than the current screen if there are no resources that better match (for example, a large-size screen will use normal-size screen resources if necessary).**

O paragrafo em *bold* explica porque o tablet(*large-size*) está a usar os recursos definidos para *normal-size*:

> (...)Especificamente, ao selecionar recursos com base nos qualificadores de tamanho, o sistema irá utilizar os recursos definidos para uma tela menor que a tela atual, se não houver recursos que melhor se adequam (por exemplo, um *large-size screen* usará os recursos definidos para *normal-size screen* se necessário).

Você definiu recursos para *layout-normal-land* mas não para *layout-large-land*.
O tablet, quando na posição *landscape*, como não encontra recursos definidos para esta situação(*layout-large-land*), utilizará os recursos definidos para uma tela menor(*layout-normal-land*).

---

Na versão Android 3.2 foram introduzidos [novos qualificadores de tamanho](http://developer.android.com/intl/pt-br/guide/practices/screens_support.html#NewQualifiers) que oferecem mais controle na definição dos recursos a usar por cada tamanho de tela.

Agora, os tamanhos que você especificar usando estes qualificadores, não são os tamanhos de tela reais. Em vez disso, os tamanhos são para a largura ou a altura em unidades *dp* que terão de estar disponíveis para o *layout*.

São 3 os qualificadores:

- **Menor largura:** `sw<N>dp`
  Use esse qualificador para garantir que, independentemente da orientação atual da tela, a sua aplicação tem, pelo menos, `<N>` *dps* de largura disponíveis para sua interface.
  Exemplos de utilização:  `sw600dp`, `sw720dp`
- **Largura da tela disponível:** `w<N>dp`
  Especifica a largura mínima `<N>` necessária em *dps* para que os recursos possam ser usados. O valor correspondente do sistema para a largura muda quando a orientação da tela alterna entre retrato e paisagem para reflectir a largura real actual que está disponível.
  Assim, esta opção pode ser usada para especificar a largura mínima necessária para o layout,tanto em retrato como em paisagem, evitando ter de usar qualificadores de tamanho e qualificadores de orientação juntos.
  Exemplos de utilização:  `w600dp`, `w720dp`
- **Altura da tela disponível:** `h<N>dp`
  O mesmo que o anterior só que relativo à altura.
  A maioria dos aplicativos não necessitará deste qualificador, considerando que geralmente é o possível usar o *scroll* vertical havendo, portanto, mais altura disponível, enquanto que a largura é mais rígida.
  Exemplos de utilização:  `h600dp`, `h720dp`

Comment: Certo, eu criei uma pasta layout-large-land e coloquei a copia do layout que eu não queria que fosse afetado.

Comment: Considere usar os novos qualificadores, eles normalmente permitem diminuir o número de *layouts* a definir.